# How to make type safe method in class shared via MEF?

Tags: c#, mef

I have class which I want to export via MEF. In this example it's string type Displayer but in program will be many special type Displayers. I will do ImportMany<*IDisplayer> to get a list of available Displayers, and I will choose the Displayer from that list, for a given object to show.

My question how would be possible to make Display method type save? Or cast in it type safe? And still have Displayer usable via MEF.

P.S.
Using MEF I can't make interface like IDisplayer<*T>, because I will be not able to get a ImportMany<*IDisplayer<*T>> or something.

```csharp
[DisplayableTypes(typeof(String))]
public class StringObjectDisplayer : IDisplayer
{
    public void Display(object objectToDisplay)
    {
        var displayableObject = (string)objectToDisplay;
    }

    private Type GetAttributeParamenters()
    {
        return GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayableTypesAttribute), true).OfType<DisplayableTypesAttribute>().First().SupportedType;
    }
}

public class DisplayableTypesAttribute : ExportAttribute, IExportableElement
{
    public DisplayableTypesAttribute(Type supportedType)
        : base(typeof(IDisplayer))
    {
        SupportedType = supportedType;
    }

    public Type SupportedType { get; private set; }
}

public interface IDisplayer
{
    void Display(object objectToDisplay);
}

public interface IExportableElement
{
    Type SupportedType { get; }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to export open generics?  If so, you might want to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/01/getting-started-with-convention-based-part-registration-in-mef-version-2.aspx

Comment: I would like to do that or make cast in Display method type safe. But in article you gave nothing about generics. But found another useful information. So thanks.